# How to make a sticky CTA under navbar, that closes when clicked?

Tags: javascript, html, css

How do I make a sticky CTA under navbar, that closes when clicked in the CTA-button or the X. This could be used to run a campaign on your website, or make users aware any sales going on.

This is what I am looking for: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lrsxI.jpg

```css
#navbar {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
}

#navbar a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}


.sticky {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%
}
```

```html
<div class="sticky" id="navbar">
  <a href="#">Home</a>
  <a href="#" >News</a>
  <a href="#">Contact</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

One approach using [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).

Wrap the menu and CTA in separate containers within the `#navbar`. Then apply flexbox properties to both. I've removed `float` from the `a` elements in this example.

```css
.menu,
.cta {
  display: flex;
}

#navbar a {
  display: inline-block;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.sticky {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%
}

.menu {
  background-color: #333;
}

.cta {
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background: red;
}

.cta button {
  margin-left: 1em;
  background: yellow;
  border: none;
  padding: .5em;
}
```

```html
<div class="sticky" id="navbar">
  <div class="menu">
    <a href="#">Home</a>
    <a href="#">News</a>
    <a href="#">Contact</a>
  </div>
  <div class="cta">
    <p>Limited...</p>
    <button>Buy</button>
  </div>
</div>
```